# GNU Makefile generate multiple targets from multiple prerequisites using single recipe execution

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a tool `foo` that can take in one or more inputs and generate corresponding outputs. For example, `foo a.in` produces `a.out` and `foo a.in b.in` produces `a.out` and `b.out`. 
`a.out` only depends on `a.in`, and `b.out` only depends on `b.in`.

While the tool can be run on single inputs, it is more efficient to run with multiple inputs, so while I can use the rule

```
%.out: %.in
    foo $?
```

to generate each `out` file individually, I would like to batch them into a single call to `foo`.

With pattern rules, I can generate multiple targets using a single execution of a recipe:

```
a%out b%out: a%in b%in
    foo $?
```

However, `a.out` now unnecessarily depends on `b.in` and `b.out` now unnecessarily depends on `a.in`.

```
stamp: a.in b.in a.out b.out
    cat
```

How can I generate multiple targets from multiple inputs using a single recipe execution when there is only a one-to-one dependency between the prerequisites and targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.INTERMEDIATE` staging file and a timestamp file can do this

```
.INTERMEDIATE: list

stamp: list
    foo `cat list`
    touch stamp

list: a.out b.out a.in b.in
    @:

%out: %in
    echo $? >> list
```